# Using python libraries outside of python distribution

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I have installed Python 2.7 through the Anaconda distribution. Now I would like to use some of the included libraries outside of Anaconda. Using sklearn works fine from the Anaconda prompt. However, when running

```
import sklearn
```

from a .py script in Rhino, I get the following error:

```
Message: No module named _check_build
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of C:\Users\tsawen\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build:
setup.py                  setup.pyc                 _check_build.pyd
__init__.py               __init__.pyc
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.

Traceback:
  line 31, in raise_build_error, "C:\Users\tsawen\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py"
  line 46, in <module>, "C:\Users\tsawen\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py"
  line 56, in <module>, "C:\Users\tsawen\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py"
  line 1, in <module>, "C:\Users\tsawen\AppData\Local\Temp\TempScript.py"
```

Some previous discussion here points to the installation being faulty. However, since importing sklearn within Anaconda works fine, Python seems to have been installed properly.

Can anybody help out with using package outside of the distribution?